# mongoose save not working in second part of if statement

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a function in my Node/Express API where I first check to see if a "Contact" exists in my "Contacts" collection. If it does, I do an update. If one doesn't exist with the email in the query, then I create a new one.

If a contact exists, the contact.save() works. But if the contact doesn't exist, the contact.save() generates an error message saying "contact.save() is not a function.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Hoping someone out there can see it easy enough and give me some advice.

Here is the code:

```
  // SEARCH IF CONTACT EXISTS IN SENDERS CONTACTS -  BY OWNERID AND EMAIL IN EMAILS
  Contact.findOne({'owner_id': req.body.owner_id, 'emails.email_address':req.body.invited_email}, function(err, contact){
    if(err)
      console.log('Error in looking for contact.');


    // IF A CONTACT EXISTS ---
    if(contact){

      console.log('--> CONTACT FOUND');

          // SET CONTACT SHARED INFORMATION
          contact.shared.invite_id = req.body.invited_first_name + req.body.invited_last_name + req.body.owner_id;
          contact.shared.profile_id = req.body.profile_id;
          contact.shared.first_name = req.body.first_name;
          contact.shared.company = req.body.company;
          contact.shared.title = req.body.title;
          contact.shared.last_name = req.body.last_name;
          contact.shared.initial = req.body.initial;
          contact.shared.linkedin = req.body.linkedin;
          contact.shared.google = req.body.google;
          contact.shared.facebook = req.body.facebook;
          contact.shared.pinterest = req.body.pinterest;
          contact.shared.twitter = req.body.twitter;
          contact.shared.emails = req.body.emails;
          contact.shared.phones = req.body.phones;
          contact.shared.addresses = req.body.addresses;
          contact.shared.link = req.body.invited_first_name + req.body.invited_last_name + req.body.owner_id;


          // ADD TO ALERT INFORMING SENDER THAT HE/SHE SHARED INFO
          alerts.genShare(req.body.owner_id, req.body.invited_first_name, req.body.invited_last_name, req.body.invited_email);

          // SAVE CONTACT INFORMATION
          contact.save(function(err){
            if(err)
              res.send(err);
            res.json(contact);
          });


          // IF INVITED IS NOT A USER - CREATE USER ACCOUNT
          if(!inviteIsUser){

            var phones = req.body.phones;
            var emails = req.body.emails;
            var addresses = req.body.addresses;

            var email = [{email_address:req.body.invited_email, email_type:'home'}];

            var share = {
              invite_id:req.body.invited_first_name + req.body.invited_last_name + req.body.owner_id,
              profile_id:req.body.profile_id,
              first_name:req.body.first_name, 
              last_name:req.body.last_name,
              initial:req.body.initial,
              birthday:req.body.birthday,
              highschool:req.body.highschool,
              college:req.body.college,
              facebook:req.body.facebook,
              linkedin:req.body.linkedin,
              google:req.body.google,
              pinterest:req.body.pinterest,
              user_image:req.body.user_image,
              emails:emails, 
              addresses:addresses, 
              phones:phones,
              shared:{}
            };

            var newContact = {
                emails: email,
                profile_id: req.body.profile_id,
                first_name: req.body.invited_first_name,
                last_name : req.body.invited_last_name,
                shared:share
            };

            //CREATE NEW USER AND ADD CONTACT FOR PERSON BEING SHARED WITH
            newUser = userCreate.genUser(req.body.invited_email, newContact);

          }


    } else {

      var contact = new Contact();

      //IF CONTACT EMAIL IS NOT FOUND, A NEW CONTACT IS CREATED
      console.log('Contact NOT found');

      var phones = req.body.phones;
      var emails = req.body.emails;
      var addresses = req.body.addresses;

      var email = [{email_address:req.body.invited_email, email_type:'home'}];

      var share = {
        invite_id:req.body.invited_first_name + req.body.invited_last_name + req.body.owner_id,
        profile_id:req.body.profile_id,
        first_name:req.body.first_name, 
        last_name:req.body.last_name,
        initial:req.body.initial,
        birthday:req.body.birthday,
        highschool:req.body.highschool,
        college:req.body.college,
        facebook:req.body.facebook,
        linkedin:req.body.linkedin,
        google:req.body.google,
        pinterest:req.body.pinterest,
        user_image:req.body.user_image,
        emails:emails, 
        addresses:addresses, 
        phones:phones,
        link:req.body.invited_first_name + req.body.invited_last_name + req.body.owner_id,
        shared:{}
      };


      contact = {
          emails: email,
          owner_id:req.body.owner_id,
          profile_id:req.body.profile_id,
          first_name: req.body.invited_first_name,
          last_name : req.body.invited_last_name,
          shared:share
      };

      console.log('Contact: ', contact);

      // SAVE CONTACT INFORMATION
      contact.save(function(err){
        if(err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json(contact);
      });



      // // IF INVITED IS NOT A USER - CREATE USER ACCOUNT
      // if(!inviteIsUser){
      //   newUser = userCreate.genUser(req.body.invited_email, contact);
      // }


      // ADD TO ALERT INFORMING SENDER THAT HE/SHE SHARED INFO
      alerts.genShare(req.body.owner_id, req.body.invited_first_name, req.body.invited_last_name, req.body.invited_email);

   }

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have rewritten your `contact` with an object:

```
contact = {
          emails: email,
          owner_id:req.body.owner_id,
          profile_id:req.body.profile_id,
          first_name: req.body.invited_first_name,
          last_name : req.body.invited_last_name,
          shared:share
      };
```

And then you try to call function save which is not present there.